# Listen for key-stroke patterns in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom-events, javascript-objects

In JavaScript, I know I can listen for specific key codes, but how can I listen for specific "patterns" of key-strokes and then fire different events when those patterns are typed?

One example of this might be a game where a player presses the keys of the secret Konami code (up, up, down, down, left, right, left, right, B, A, Start). How could I track that pattern or other patterns like it in JavaScript?

Would I accomplish this with some sort of await/async process to catch each key and wait for the next one? Is there a simpler way to go about this without exhausting the end-user's system?

I'd like to do something like this pseudo-code:

```js
on('keydown', () => {
    if (lastKeysPressed === "QWERTY") doSomething();
});
```

What's I've currently tried is logging each key typed to a string then reading the sequence of keyCodes to see if it matches like this:

```js
let typedString = "";
const secret = "This is a secret";
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    typedString += e.key;
    if (typedString.slice(-secret.length) === secret) alert('Secret typed!');
});
```

This is the closest I've gotten so far and it works for me so far for one string, but I'm having difficulty getting it to work for multiple strings to listen for and when there are capital letters in the middle of the string since the `keydown` event catches the "Shift" key as well and appends `Shift` to my `typedString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would go about this by storing each keystroke's `keyCode` into an array, and then checking the **last** X number of items in that keylogger array and match that against the patterns you want to listen for.

To keep that array lightweight as you mentioned, I would trim the array length on every keystroke to the array length of your longest pattern, which would be the maximum number of keystrokes necessary to track all your patterns.

When comparing the most recently typed keys, I am unshifting the new key codes to add them to the beginning of the `keylog` array and then comparing that to the reversed state of every pattern to check from right to left. This is crucial since we are continually trimming off the last characters from the array, the oldest characters. The most recent characters will always appear first in the `keylog` array. To make a shallow reverse of the pattern, so as not to mutate the original pattern's order, I use `.slice().reverse()`.

Lastly, in order to get accurate keyCodes for lowercase and uppercase letters, I take `e.key.charCodeAt()` if the `key` property of the event is exactly one character. Without this, all letters are rendered as uppercase and certain characters such as "slashes" will have the wrong charCode.

Try it out here:

```js
patterns = {
    "konami code": [38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,98,97,13],
    "happy birthday": "happy birthday".split("").map(e => e.charCodeAt()),
    "sticky keys": [16,16,16,16,16],
    "hello world": "hello world".split("").map(e => e.charCodeAt()),
    "todays date": `${((new Date()).getMonth() + 1).toString()}/${(new Date()).getDate().toString()}/${(new Date()).getFullYear().toString()}`.split("").map(e => e.charCodeAt())
};

const maxLength = Math.max(...Object.values(patterns).map(e => e.length));
const keylog = [];
const testArraysEqual = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.length === arr2.length && arr1.every((e,i) => e === arr2[i]);

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    keylog.unshift(e.key.length === 1 ? e.key.charCodeAt() : e.keyCode);
    if (keylog.length > maxLength) keylog.length = maxLength;
    for ([patternName, pattern] of Object.entries(patterns)) {
        if (pattern.length <= keylog.length && testArraysEqual(pattern.slice().reverse(), keylog.slice(0, pattern.length))) {
            console.log(`${patternName} pattern fired`);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
Try clicking anywhere in this result window and typing any of the following patterns:
<ul>
    <li>↑ ↑ ↓ ↓ ← → ← → b a "enter"</li>
    <li>happy birthday</li>
    <li>"shift" "shift" "shift" "shift" "shift"</li>
    <li>hello world</li>
    <li>today's date in M/D/YYYY format (e.g. `2/22/2021`)</li>
</ul>
```